# How to retrieve Handle of a State block ? Matlab

Tags: matlab, simulink, handle, stateflow

I'm actually trying to build a Stateflow with Matlab code

I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve the Handle of a State block. I tried to use get_param()  :

```
state_handle = get_param('System/Chart/State_ON', 'Handle');
```

But it returns me :

```
No block called 'State_ON' could be found.
```

Is there another solution to get Handle using the name of the state?

Edit : i found and post a solution

Comment: It would help if you showed the block... it's likely you're referencing it wrong but we have no way to tell from this question

Comment: @Wolfie i found an answer thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after many research there are 2 solutions :

[For version R2017b and after](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/rptgenext/ug/slreportgen.finder.statefinder-class.html)

`StateHandle = StateFinder(Chart Handle)`

[For versions before R2017b](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/api/accessing-existing-stateflow-objects.html)

`state_handle = ch.find('-isa','Stateflow.State','-and','Name', 'State_ON');`